# Pushing data to javascript array but the array is not growing

Tags: javascript, html, url, push

I'm trying to create a navigation system for an internal website.

To do so I'm creating an array by means of javascript that tracks the url of the page and with each new page I'm pushing that new url into the array.

Problem is, each new page seems to be overwriting the last page.

This is what is in my javascript file ... notice I only create a new array if the array doesn't already exist (it will be deleted when the person leaves the website).

```
var myURL = document.URL;

if (typeof myHistory == "undefined" || !(myHistory instanceof Array)) {
    var myHistory = [];
}

myHistory.push(myURL); 

var last_element = myHistory[myHistory.length - 1];

var number_rows = myHistory.length;
```

This what I'm using to see the values in the html ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  document.write(last_element);
  document.write(number_rows);
// -->
</script>
```

It's displaying the URL (last_element) as desired but number_rows remains at 1 when I browse between pages rather than go up to 2, 3, 4, etc which is what I hope to achieve.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Each time you refresh a page all of your javascript variables will be erased. You can try html5 local storage if you need persistence: http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please make sure you take the time to read through the [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Every time you refresh a page, JavaScript is refreshed anew. If you need to have data persistence, you'll need to use cookies, `localStorage`, or server-side data storage.

All of those options will require that you serialize to and deserialize from strings.

Here's a quick example of how you could do this using `localStorage`:

```
//closure to prevent global pollution
//it's good to be green
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var history,
        url;
    //set url here
    //I'm making the assumption that no url will have a ',' char in it
    history = localStorage['history'].split(',');
    history.push(url);
    localStorage['history'] = history.join(',');
    console.log(url, history.length);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks zzzzBov ... back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

When you browse between pages the javascript environment is re-created on each page. So you are always starting with an empty array.

Comment: Thanks Sean ... I figured it was something along those lines.